# angular5: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular5

I am trying to change the login status after the user login

**component.ts**

```
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>; 

  constructor (private auth:Auth){}

  ngOnInit (){


     this.isLoggedIn$ = this.auth.getUser()

     console.log(this.isLoggedIn$);

  }
```

**Auth.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth {

    private user:boolean = false;

     setUser(){

        this.user= true;
     }

     getUser(){
        return this.user
     }

    removeUser(){
        this.user = false;
    }

}
```

But i got the following error

> error TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'

Comment: You are expecting an `Observable` of `boolean` value but returning just a `boolean` value. This code will make more sense if you are returning `Observable` from a `http` call which maps to a `boolean` value asynchronously.

Comment: I am mocking `http` service with `Auth` class

Comment: If you are mocking then return `Observable.of(this.user)`

Comment: Are you using `isLoggedIn$` in your template? If so, you can use it like `*ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async"`

Comment: yes i am using it do i need to add a subscriber to listen the change

Answer (score 1):

If you are mocking `http` without an actual service, you can wrap the loggedIn status in an Observable as shown below for a quick fix. Take a look at rxjs and understand `Observables` for a better understanding.

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth {

    private user:boolean = false;

     setUser(){

        this.user= true;
     }

     getUser(): Observable<boolean>{
        return Observable.of(this.user)
     }

    removeUser(){
        this.user = false;
    }

}
```

Also: `console.log(this.isLoggedIn$)` will not work like that.

Comment: i am getting this error ` Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function
    at Auth.getUser`

Comment: You need to `import` those. `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: You will be better off using `Promise` + `async` function in this case.

Comment: but why its not update the value?? this component is common to all

Comment: How are you using the value? If its in template you can use `isLoggedIn$ | async`. Else you will have to `subscribe`

Comment: i am using `isLoggedIn$ | async` but its not working

Comment: @iambatman Here is a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-cuxamz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the input